# Как выделить дни в Calendar View?

Tags: java, android

Добрый день! Есть задача: выделять определенные дни цветами. Один день я выделить цветом могу,а вот несколько...даже не знаю как.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду рад хоть какой-то помощи! Заранее благодарю!
Использую material calendar view : https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview

Comment: Если вы используюте внешнюю библиотеку, указывайте на нее ссылку. Делайте дополнения, редактируя сам вопрос (кнопка "править" под вопросом), а не в комментариях к нему.

Answer (score 1):

Дружище, для этих целей не рекомендую использовать стандартный календарь, он не очень функциональный. Держи ссылку на простой в использовании и в то же время навороченный календарик https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview Хорошая документация с примерами работы.

Comment: Тут видимо модифицировать надо будет либу, автору нужно выделять два дня а между ними интервал..

Answer (score 0):

Вот несколько календарей, в которых можно выбирать несколько дат ([взято отсюда](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/calendarview.php)):

https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview

https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid

https://github.com/vikramkakkar/SublimePicker

https://github.com/Applandeo/Material-Calendar-View